# Networking in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am trying to set up a VM in VirtualBox on Linux (Fedora 22).  Its network must have the following properties:

- IP address is 192.168.1.2/24
- Default gateway is 192.168.1.1
- No DHCP
- Network connectivity to the outside world

It is not a requirement that other systems on my network be able to connect to the VM.  The VirtualBox console will suffice for the time being.

I first tried the "NAT" driver, but I can't figure out how to make it use 192.168.1.1 as its default gateway.  I have it serving DHCP addresses in 192.168.1.0/24, but it's insisting on using 192.168.1.2 as its gateway.  I also tried using the "NAT Network" driver, using the network range 192.168.1.0/24 and DHCP disabled (as described at https://virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service); after manually setting the network address and default route in my VM, I get no upstream connectivity and I can't even ARP 192.168.1.1.  If I use "NAT Network" with DHCP enabled, it again uses 192.168.1.2 as the default gateway, and I *still* don't get upstream connectivity.  The "Bridged Adapter" driver isn't appropriate because the VM is hosted on a machine that uses a different network range (172.16.1.0/24).

At the moment, the OS inside the VM is a Gentoo installation CD image.  The eventual purpose of this VM is to be a test environment for a production device; hence, it must use the same network configuration as the real device.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Edit: It seems that VirtualBox can't do this, at least without jumping through a lot of hoops like making changes to the host's network setup or adding a second VM to act as default gateway for the first.  I guess I'll have to try some other VM manager.

Comment: It is a little unclear how you want the system to work, other than that you want to port forward to the VM from your physical router. That by itself indicates Bridged networking. Does the system you are exposing to the LAN/WAN consist of multiple VMs? and what specifically do you mean by "Bridged isn't appropriate because my host network is different"? please describe the "host network" and why it is unsuitable (the term is a little ambiguous).

Comment: I added some more details about the purpose of this VM and why a "Bridged Adapter" isn't appropriate.

I don't want to port-forward anything to the VM at the moment.  It just needs to act like a computer connected to a network.

Comment: so why wouldn't you want the VM to operate on the 172.16.1. network?  then it would be completely accessible to the host and to all other entities on that network? if not, use NAT, and accept that the default gateway will always be the VMs IP. it won't be accessible to entities on the 172. network unless you configure the VBox connection to port forward to the VM. the same is true with NAT Network (that you must forward ports), but then the gateway will be 192.168.1.1. NAT connections act like there is a virtual router between the host and the NAT, so with NAT you always forward ports.

Comment: I don't want it to use a 172.16.1.0/24 address because the VM is meant to simulate something on a 192.168.1.0/24 network.  And the VM needs to use particular addresses because those are the addresses used by the system it's simulating.  The VM doesn't need to be accessible to everthing else on my network -- I just need the VM to be able to access the Internet through my network.  Hence NAT is appropriate.  And with a NATed network inside a VM environment, I *should* (in principle) be able to set up the network however I want, regardless of what addresses my real, physical network uses.

Comment: all that is true of NAT Network, so see the description here on how to create a NAT Network for your VMs to use: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service

Comment: I did that.  And as described in my question, "I get no upstream connectivity and I can't even ARP 192.168.1.1".  The "NAT Network" driver is described as being "experimental" -- does anyone know if it actually works or if it's liable to fail in strange ways?

Comment: have you tried enabling DHCP, and confirming that the gateway is at .1? the documentation says it is subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may look counter-intuitive at first, the net you need to solve your problem is **Host only**: it is the only one the allows you to control every aspect of the connection. I will assume you are running some flavor of Linux both as host and as guest, if not please adapt accordingly.

Before configuring the VM, on the VirtualBox GUI, File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-Only Networks. Add one such network by hitting the plus sign on the right-hand side of the window, a new network called **vboxnet0** will appear, now hit the screwdriver. Under IPv4 address write `192.168.1.1`, under mask write `255.255.255.0`. Now hit *DHCP Server* and make sure it is disabled.

On the host, you will now see

```
            ip addr show
```

that you have a new interface called *vboxnet0*. Make sure that you forward correctly requests from the VM by issuing (as sudo)

```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(this assumes your host is connected to the internet via an interface called `eth0`, if not change accordingly).

Now back to the VirtualBox GUI, select your VM, then Network -> Adapter 1 -> Enable Network Adapter, under `Attached to` choose **Host-only Adapter**, and under `Name` choose **vboxnet0**.

Boot the VM, then set up a static IP address. This depends on the guest OS. I will simply show you how to do this in Linux, if you have Windows or Mac OS X and you do not know how to do it you will have to look it up by Googling, it is not difficult.

Issue the following commands, always as sudo:

```
    ip link set dev eth0 down
    ip addr flush dev eth0
    ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0 
    ip link set dev eth0 up
    ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
    echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
    echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

The above assumes your main interface in the VM is called eth0, if not please change accordingly. All of the above can easily be scripted, but it depends on Linux distro. You are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

In virtual box your physical machine ie HOST will be your gateway.
If you want to change your gateway, try  to configure HOST virtualbox adapter as you wish.
If you enable NAT and you want to communicate from outside to your vm, you have to create translation entry in virtualbox.